# Intl.NumberFormat is not working properly in IE11?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internationalization, intl, react-intl

I am using Intl library of native Javascript to show formatted number in English and Chinese.
It is working properly in Chrome, but it is not working in IE11.

For English locale following is the code and output:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { notation: "compact" , compactDisplay: "short" }).format(91005);
```

Expected output: 91K 
Output Getting in Chrome: 91K 
Output Getting in IE11: 91,005 ---> Incorrect Output

Similarly for Chinese locale following is the code and output:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('zh-cn', { notation: "compact" , compactDisplay: "short" }).format(91005);
```

Expected Output: 9.1万 
Output Getting Chrome: 9.1万 
Output Getting in IE11: 91,005 --> Incorrect Output

Need help on this to solve this issue ?

Comment: were you able to find solution for this ?

Comment: No, still not able to find the solution,

Answer (score 1):

IE11 has an old version of `Intl.NumberFormat` so u need to polyfill using this: https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat

Comment: Polyfill doesn't seem to work in IE11. Producing console errors.

Comment: Nvm, required three other polyfills.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk do you have any working example ?

Comment: @sam_dev `react-app-polyfill/ie11` and `react-app-polyfill/stable` did the job for me.